# Properly detect if SD card is available

Tags: android

I use the following code to check if the SD card is available but on a Samsung Galaxy II and Note devices that run Android 4.x and later the OS simulate having a SD card even if in reality there is no SD card on the device.

```
private boolean isSDCardAvailable() {
    return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
}
```

If SD card is available I then call getExternalCacheDir() get the directory else I display erro r to the user and call getCacheDir() to use internal storage.

The method above return TRUE and ALL devices even if they don't have a SD card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see this method is available since API level 11, which let you know if Internal Memory working as External storage. in some devices `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns true even if SD-Card is not available. read below docs for details.

```
public static boolean isExternalStorageEmulated ()
```

> Added in API level 11
>
> Returns whether the device has an external storage device which is emulated. ***If true, the device does not have real external storage, and the directory returned by getExternalStorageDirectory() will be allocated using a portion of the internal storage system.***

**Certain system services, such as the package manager, use this to determine where to install an application.**

> Emulated external storage may also be encrypted - see setStorageEncryption(android.content.ComponentName, boolean) for additional details.

[Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageEmulated%28%29)

Comment: I tried to use isExternalStorageEmulated but my Samsung Galaxy Pocket that run Android 2.3 also emulate the SD card and this method isn't available in API level 10 :(

Comment: Yes that is true, I have written this method is only available after API 11. be careful while using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable;

private void checkExternalMedia() {
    mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }
}
```